# JTable column stops working after a certain column number

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablemodel

I am under the impression that after column 4 [index 3] the rest of my jtable does react to formatting or data validation.

As you can see in this image the colour just stops after column 4:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku71x.png]

Declaration:

```
private final JTable table = new JTable(new TableModelDB("all"));
private final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

Here is all my code relating to the jtable:

```
    JFormattedTextField ftext = new JFormattedTextField();
    try {
        MaskFormatter mask = new MaskFormatter("####-##-##");
        mask.setPlaceholderCharacter('_');
        mask.setAllowsInvalid(false);
        mask.install(ftext);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("error: " + e);
    }
    table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, new MyCellEditor());
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellEditor(new MyCellEditor(ftext));
    table.setRowHeight(30);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.getModel().addTableModelListener(this);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, cr);
    table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false);
    resizeColumnWidth();
    table.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
    table.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
```

Data Validation using CellEditor (The validation works just fine until column=4, using println() I figured out that the stopCellEditing method was never called):

```
    private boolean editValidation(String data) {
    System.out.println("editValidation");
    int column = table.getSelectedColumn();

    if (data == null || data.trim().isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("c0");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot leave a field blank");
        return false;
    }

    if (column == 1 && data.length() > 255) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Income name is too long (Max 255 characters)");
        return false;
    }
    if (column == 2 && data.length() > 255) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Category name is too long (Max 255 characters)");
        return false;
    }
    if (column == 3) {
        if (data.contains("_")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid date");
            return false;
        } else {
            try {
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                df.setLenient(false);
                df.parse(data);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid date");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (column == 4) {
        System.out.println("c4");
        if (!data.matches("^[0-9]+")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Amount contains non-number elements");
            return false;
        } else if (Integer.parseInt(data) <= 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Income cannot be less than or equal to zero");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public class MyCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

    public MyCellEditor() {
        super(new JTextField());
    }

    MyCellEditor(JFormattedTextField ftext) {
        super(ftext);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        System.out.println("stopCellEditing");
        final JTextField field = (JTextField) getComponent();
        if (editValidation(field.getText())) {
            System.out.println("case t");
            field.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            return super.stopCellEditing();
        }
        System.out.println("case f");
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        field.setBackground(Color.RED);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Cell Renderer (even though I made everything light grey, the columns after index 3 weren't applied):

```
public class CustomCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
                isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);

        c.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
//        if (col == 0) {
//            c.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
//        } else {
//            c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
//        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Table Model:

```
public final class TableModelDB extends AbstractTableModel {

    private final WorkingClass wc = new WorkingClass();
    private final int startRows = 1;

    private final String[] columnNames = {"Income ID", "Income Name", "Category", "Entry Date", "Amount", "Delete"};
    private Object[][] data;

    public TableModelDB(String type) {
        try {
            ResultSet rs = wc.searchIncomeRS(type);
            int rowCount = wc.rowCount();
            int count = 0, amount, total = 0;
            Object[][] temp = new Object[rowCount + startRows][6];
            while (rs.next()) {
                temp[count][0] = rs.getString("ID");
                temp[count][1] = rs.getString("EntryName");
                temp[count][2] = rs.getString("Category");
                Date date = new Date(rs.getDate("EntryDate").getTime());
                temp[count][3] = wc.strDate(date);
                amount = rs.getInt("Amount");
                total += amount;
                temp[count][4] = amount;
                temp[count++][5] = false;
            }
            temp[count][4] = total;
            data = temp;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("error: " + ex);
        }
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
        for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++) {
            Object o = getValueAt(row, col);
            if (o != null) {
                return o.getClass();
            }
        }
        return Object.class;
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return !(data[row][col] == null || data[row][0] == null || col == 0);
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        data[row][col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

}
```

If any kind soul could tell me why the columns don't respond it would be greatly appreciated, any other errors or criticism are welcomed too

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a few test classes I realised only columns with Strings got the formatting and the DV, so I changed it to:

```
        table.setDefaultEditor(String.class, new MyCellEditor());//DV
        table.setDefaultEditor(Integer.class, new MyCellEditor());//DV
        table.setDefaultEditor(Boolean.class, new MyCellEditor());//DV
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellEditor(new MyCellEditor(ftext));//Mask
        table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new CustomCellRenderer());//color
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Integer.class, new CustomCellRenderer());//color
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, new CustomCellRenderer());//color
```

Now everything works

Comment: to change the background of all the rows in the table there is no need for a custom renderer. Just use `table.setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY)`. You can also check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for more creating rendering of row data.

Comment: @camickr thank you very much for your advice. May I please ask you another question? I cannot figure out where and how to check if the person did not change the data in the table. i.e. they just clicked off the data without changing (i have a confirm dialog box that will ask you to confirm that you want to change the data and this pops up even if the data stayed the same).

Comment: Well I don't know if you are asking about changing data in a single cell, or multiple columns in a single row, or multiple rows. In any case the answer is you need to manage this. There is no copy of the data before/after to do a comparison on. Check out the [Table Cell Listener](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/) which may help. Using this class you could set a "changed" variable every time an edit is made. Then your popup dialog would need to check this variable at the appropriate time. If you need more help then ask a separate question with a proper [mre].

Comment: @camickr thank you so much I will give this a try :)